# Query sql nodejs loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

Olá estou com uma duvida acho que poderiam me ajudar, a algum problema em executar uma função duas vezes no mesmo script

exemplo tenho essa função

```js
exports.getValueMsg = function(){
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pconn.pool.query("SELECT b.numero_serie, b.grupo_msg, b.index_msg, b.valor_msg FROM  bor_msg b ", (err, rows) => {
            if (!err) {
               count = Object.keys(rows).length;
               while(i<count){
                  console.log(i);
                  dadosMsg = rows.rows[i];     
                  i++;
                  return resolve(dadosMsg);
               }       
                        
            } else {
                reject(err);
                console.log(err);
        }
    });  
   })
}
```

e ela  me retorna os resultados da query normalmente. Mais quando faço a chamada desta função ex abaixo

```js
  const exec = async() => { 
    try {
      var macroLength = await dbMsg.getValueMsg();
      var count = Object.keys(macroLength).length;
    
      for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
        var valueMsg = await dbMsg.getValueMsg();
        console.log(valueMsg);

        macro = await xmlTemplates.xml_16_begin(valueMsg);      
        
        clientOut.write(macro);

        await fc.wait(2200);

        clientOut.write(xmlTemplates.xml_16_end());

        await fc.wait(3000);
        
        dbMsg.upStatusMsg(statusMsg, valueMsg);
        
        setTimeout(function(){
          if(vDataOutObj.Package.Header._attributes.Id == 116){

            console.log(vDataOutObj.Package.Header._attributes.Id);

            dbMsg.upStatusMsg(statusMsg2, valueMsg);
         }
         
        },3100);
      }
  
    }catch (error) {
       console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

ele me retorna os resultado duplicados e não consegue percorrer o loop totalmente, acho que é porque estou executando a função duas vezes...por isso ele duplica os resultados e não me retorna todos..porém se eu não executar a função **getValueMsg()** duas vezes, como vou decidir até onde meu **For** deve percorrer

Answer (score 0):

A query ficaria basicamente assim removendo o laço de repetiçao

```js
exports.getValueMsg = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pconn.pool.query("SELECT b.numero_serie, b.grupo_msg, b.index_msg, b.valor_msg FROM bor_msg b where b.id_tipo = '16'",
                (err, result) => {
                    if (result) {
                        resolve(result);
                    } else {
                        reject(err);
                    }
                }
            );  
   });
}
```

E a chamada para percorrer os results da query ficaria assim

```js
const exec = async() => { 
    
    try {
      
      const queryResult = await dbMsg.getValueMsg();

      for(let i=0; i<queryResult.rows.length; i++) {
        
        const valueMsg = queryResult.rows[i]; 

        console.log(valueMsg);
       
       .......................
       
       ......................
       
      }
     
   }catch (error) {
       console.log(error);
    }
}
```